# Font does not change in google chrome and chromium

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, chromium, google

I tried to change the font settings in google chrome and chromium, re-install them, restart my computer, delete the related folders in .config, the font still remains the same.

[image: screenshot in chromium]

Comment: Have  you tried running `fc-cache -rf` ?

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: I know you have removed related files from `.config` but try creating a new profile too it might help...

Comment: Just installed firefox, it has the same font!